# Is it possible to manage the Google Play Console Email List programmatically via an API?

Tags: google-api, google-play-console, google-api-python-client, google-play-developer-api

The Google Play Email List management area in the Google Play Console allows admins to enter comma separated email addresses or upload a CSV.  The Google Play Console makes an http `POST` to `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/testersemaillist?account={account}`

[image]

Is it possible to manage these lists via an API?  The one above doesn't seem like it's intended for non-google use.

I see there is a Google Play Developer API, but I don't see anything that looks like it would allowing managing the email lists.  [This](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/testers) is the closest thing I found, which allows updating Google Groups or Google+ Communities associated with the testing trakcs, but not the email list.

Here is documentation to add beta testers to Test Flight:

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_beta_tester
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/add_beta_testers_to_a_beta_group

Comment: Looking for the same thing. It will be useful for creating a closed testing group where people can signup themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Google Play Console API, while editing users does seem possible, userlists aren't supported:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.testers

```
Resource: Testers
The testers of an app. The resource for TestersService. Note: while it is possible in the Play Console UI to add testers via email lists, email lists are not supported by this resource.
```